# Unable to update profile picture - Unusual error

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, profile-picture

I am unable to update my profile picture. It is showing me this error:

[image]

I tried using JPG, JPEG and PNG image format but none work, I also tried using different options such as 'click here' and 'drag and drop' image, but still none work. How to fix this?

Comment: I just tried to change mine to the Gravatar, and I got this error message when pressing "Save changes just for this community". Then I went to try to change the prose instead, and I got the same message. So I don't think this is limited to changing the avatar.

Comment: Also posted at meta.stackexchange in [Unable to edit user profile: "Unusual error updating your profile"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370641/unable-to-edit-user-profile-unusual-error-updating-your-profile)

Comment: Should be fixed now, sorry about that. More details over at the report on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370641/unable-to-edit-user-profile-unusual-error-updating-your-profile

Comment: Thanks, it's working now.